# Повторяющиеся элементы массива

Tags: массивы, сортировка, c++

Есть произвольный массив, в котором нужно отсортировать повторяющиеся элементы по уменьшению и вывести общее кол-во повторений.
Решил реализовать следующим образом: сначала просто отсортировать массив методом пузырька, после чего циклом прогнать условие на совпадения, и если они есть просто выводить их на экран и добавлять к счетчику совпадений +1, таким образом избегая пересоздания массива.
Написал следующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX 50

main(){
    int array[MAX], n, i, j, tmp, repeat;
    printf("Number of elements array = "); scanf("%i",&n);
    printf("Type array elements:\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Array[%i] = ",i); scanf("%i",&array[i]);
        if(array[i]==0) break;
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        tmp = 0;
        for(j=(i+1); j<n; j++){
            if(array[i] < array[j]){
                tmp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The result of sorting:\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%i\t",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\nRepeated elements:\n");
    for(i=0,tmp=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=(i+1); j<n; j++){
            if(array[i] == array[j]){
                tmp++;
                printf("%i\t%i\t",array[i],array[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    if(tmp > 0){
        printf("\nThe number of repetitions: %i",tmp);
    } else printf("\nThe array elements is not repeated");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Как вы уже могли догадаться, алгоритм сравнения работает не корректно, а именно:
[Скрин запущенной программы](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/812/image2ls.png/)

Comment: Ваш алгоритм выводит то, что вы в нем описали! У вас два цикла, и элемент первого сравнивается с каждым элементов второго, поэтому у вас и получается 2 шестерки, 2 пятерки и столько четверок. А что именно вам нужно получить на выходе? Просто перечисление повторяющихся чисел: 6,5,4? И еще вопрос, если в массиве три "4" - это считается как два повторения (tmp+2) или как одно?

Comment: К примеру в массиве числа 4,5,6,8,4,6,8,8,7,5. В конечном итоге на экран должно вывести: 8,8,8,6,6,5,5,4,4 и повторений 5. То есть 6 повторяется один раз, 5 один раз, 4 один раз и 8 два раза.

Comment: Лучше использовать стандартные встроенные функции сортировки. На С++ предпочтительно применять шаблон STL sort(). Использовать его проще простого.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   printf("\nRepeated elements:\n");
    for(i=0,tmp=0; i<n-1; i++){
       if (array[i]==array[i+1]) {
        printf("%i\t",array[i]);
        for(j=(i+1); j<n && array[j]==array[i]; j++){
               tmp++;
               printf("%i\t",array[j]);
        }
        i=j-1;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Недавно писал похожую программу, только без сортировки

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int arr[10],i,y,c, e, b,n=0,sum=0, arr2[10];
cout<<"Vvedite 10 chisel:\n";
//Заполняем массив
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    cin>>arr[i];
}
cout<<"Chisla:\n";
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
y= arr[i];
for (c=i+1; c<10; c++)
    {
    e=arr[c];
        if (y==e)
            {
                sum+=1;
            }
    }
    if (sum>0)
        {
            for (b=0; b<10; b++)
            {
                if (arr2[b]==arr[i])
                    break;
                else
                {
                    if (b==9)
                    {
                    arr2[n]=arr[i];
                    n++;
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
sum=0;
}

for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
 {
    cout<<arr2[i];
 }
cout<<"\n";
system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```